# aws instance froze, how to find out what went wrong

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, couchdb

So we have a instance on AWS that runs CouchDB which was down and not accessible until we rebooted the box (which took a long time).

The instance is back up now and I am trying to figure out what went wrong.  At the time of the problem, I was not able to ssh into it. I've look at the CouchDB log and /var/log/syslog and nothing is jumping out.  Where else can I check to see if there is anything wrong before contacting AWS?

Comment: It's certainly possible that AWS had a hardware-related failure that cased your instance to freeze.  If that was the case then you wouldn't find anything in any of the instances logs other than indications that it just stopped responding and/or spontaneously rebooted.  You probably should just go ahead and contact AWS support to see if the hardware your instance was running on at the time suffered some sort of failure.